# How do I reposition the Nav/Toolbar when toggling Status Bar?

Tags: autolayout, ios7, uistatusbar, xcode5

**Environment:** AutoLayout within iOS 6/7, Xcode 5.

I understand that to adjust the NavBar to accommodate the status bar, I set NavBar's background Image to 64 bits high (ref: WWDC 2013 Video Lecture #214).

[image]

Is there a convenient way to toggle the presence of this status bar while *repositioning* the NavBar up flush against the container view (and vice/versa)?

**Added concern:** I need to work with both iOS 6 & 7.

iOS 6 has the solid status bar.  Hence, I would have to change the NavBar's background image in iOS 7 to automatically accommondate the status bar... or

...am I correct that I can merely set the status bar to OPAQUE to have similar positioning in both iOS 6/7 environments?

Comment: Just FYI: your question violates the NDA that you agreed to when you signed up for the Apple iOS Developer Program. That's your risk to take, obviously, but it's going to be a little tricky for anyone here to give you an answer that works with iOS7 without violating the NDA themselves.

Comment: Truly sorry.  Shall behave accordingly.

Comment: No problem. Hold on to your question until the NDA lifts (when iOS 7 is released) or ask your question in the Apple Developer forums (currently down but hopefully back up soon).

Answer (score 0):

DoubleEncore has a blog post that may help with the status bar issues ([link](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/)). Also there is a section of the UITransition Guide that deals specifically with Bars that you should review ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW1)). You should review the UIBarButtonItemClass Reference ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)), which has *important* sample code for the **UICatalog** showing the different UIKit objects ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710)). These references should give you complete control of the UIKit objects in your project.